# Can't update files in jar in vim

Tags: java, maven, vim, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

I had packaged a jar with all dependencies in it by using Maven assembly plugin, after that  I want to edit some configuration files enter code here in vim, but I got below errors when I saved.

> ***error*** (zip#Write) sorry, unable to update /Users/boreas/IdeaProjects/hummi
>       ngbird/target/hummingbird-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar with log4j.xml

How to solve it?

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have zip and unzip installed (on Ubuntu you'd run `sudo apt-get install zip && sudo apt-get install unzip`).

Also make sure the file has write permissions for the current user.

Comment: I assume you have unzip, since you're able to edit the zip file, but for the completeness of the answer I added also unzip.

Comment: This also allows `vim` to edit zip/war file entries and save the results.